# jstree - Is there a way to NOT automatically check/uncheck the ancestors and descendants?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I need to show a tree where user can select specific nodes.

When click a checkbox, it should NOT automatically select all it's ancestors and decedents but only check the checkbox on which user has clicked.

**Update**
Example

When I select Cell Phones, it should not select all it's ancestors as you see in the image. Same way assume it has 3 children iPhone, Nokia, Samsung then they also should not be affected by whether I select Cell Phone or not.

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of the scenario?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan  The attached image is closer to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of option we need to set for that.

```
'keep_selected_style': false,
'three_state': false,
'cascade': ''
```

Here is a fiddle to achieve the effect I mentioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/m83gjxvr/